# Set Silent Mode programmatically in Android by Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

how to set the phone (Android OS) programmatically in silent mode by using Phonegap (JavaScript)
is there any plugin or should I create my own plugin if yes How?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own plugin [developing-phonegap-plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)
and you can set the ringer mode to silent or normal whatever you want in android using AudioManager.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

You can also set the value to :

```
RINGER_MODE_NORMAL, RINGER_MODE_SILENT, or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.
```

Also add the following permission in the manifest file:

```
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS.
```

http://sree.cc/google/android/code-to-change-phone-mode-to-normalsilent-or-vibrate-in-android